# cPanel/WHM skeleton directory: placeholder for username and domain name

Tags: cpanel, whm

I'm setting up a skeleton directory in WHM. Does anyone know of a way to add the username and domain name to those files when the account is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. Here are some resources for anyone seeking similar solutions:

For php, the cpanel account details are stored in $argv, utilizing this you can setup wordpress:
https://github.com/BizziBiz/Wordpress-Auto-Installer/blob/master/postwwwacct

cPanel blog article about automation after account creation:
http://blog.cpanel.net/frequently_asked_scripts_how_do_i_automate_xyz_after_creating_an_account/